# AngularJS form validation not working with selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, selectize.js

### Validate selectize field drop-down in angular js form with $error

```
<form name="postJobForm">
```

**This is selectize dropdown**

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectUser"  name="selectUser"   
ng-model="selectUser"   required></select>

<small ng-show="postJobForm.selectUser.$error.required 
&& postJobForm.selectUser.$touched" class="errorMsg ">
Please complete this required field.</small>
```

**This is the simple drop-down which is working fine as expected (not selectize)**

```
<select class="form-control " name="requestedType" ng-model="requestedType "
id="requestedType"  
ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in data.requestedTypes" 
ng-init="requestedType = ''" required>
</select>

<small ng-show="postJobForm.requestedType.$error.required 
&& postJobForm.requestedType.$touched" class="errorMsg ">
Please complete this required field.</small>

</form>
```

This is how my selectize is loading:

```
//assigned to -- recruiter role
$scope.$selectUser = $('#selectUser').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    placeholder: "Search by name...",
    options: $scope.data.recruiter_users,
    create: false,
    sortField: {
        field: 'name',
        direction: 'asc'
    }
});
```

[image]

[image]

I am trying to achieve same validation like the `Requested Type`, but when i touch and focus out it is not working as expected

where I am doing wrong..?

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Use [tag:angular-ui-select]